# Cannot create a Metastore in Databricks

Tags: databricks, aws-databricks, databricks-unity-catalog

Followed all steps from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cylJ9hPmt7c , but still getting an error [here is an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Fx1L.png). Can't figure out why. Tried different regions also. I have account admin on databricks console and admin in aws, so it not the source of the problem.

Can it be an issue with 14-days trial?
Pressed **force create** - metastore was created. Is it the wrong way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Databricks does not support Unity Catalog in the free trial on AWS. They do on Azure (and I have confirmed this in my own personal Azure Databricks 14-day trial) but according to the Databricks solutions architecture team they do not support it on AWS.

Keep in mind the free trials still incur cloud costs, so you'll still pay for S3, EC2, and data transfer costs on AWS during your trial. If you want to try out Unity Catalog, I recommend either using the free trial on Azure, or use a Premium databricks account on AWS then use SQL Serverless for the warehouse (this is very quick to spin up and down, and you only pay in DBUs since the compute runs in Databricks' account).